# How to scan "16 digits, expiration date, 3 digits" on credit card in React Native app?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to scan 16digits, expiration date, 3 digits on credit card in React Native app?

I used "react-native-awesome-card-io" and I was succeed to launch scanning screen on RN app.

And inside launching screen, there is instruction saying "Hold card here. It will scan automatically." But nothing work.

This is my code from [sample](https://github.com/Kerumen/react-native-awesome-card-io/blob/master/Example/App.js#L1).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { CardIOModule, CardIOUtilities } from 'react-native-awesome-card-io'

export default class CardIOExample extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      CardIOUtilities.preload()
    }
  }

  scanCard() {
    console.log(1111111);
    CardIOModule.scanCard()
      .then(card => {
        // the scanned card
        console.log('card=>', card);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // the user cancelled
        console.log('err=>', err);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.scanCard.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Scan card!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

How to scan it? And how to save it to app?

> ```
> When I didn't focus on card exactly, the instruction appears on screen.
> ```

[image]

> ```
> If I focus on card exactly, screen looks dark. But nothing happened.
> ```

[image]

Comment: Hi, SatelBill were you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @StateBill, did you fix it?

Comment: I didn't fixed the error, so I opened new issue on this package. Staff also told me that this CVC scanning function is still in development progress.
So I decided to choose another module "anyline-ocr-react-native-module". And it is working well. I highly recommend this package.